# Remmina: Unable to connect to remote RDP server <server name>

Tags: networking, rdp, remmina

I have been using Remmina on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop to connect to a remote Windows system since  February without any problems. This past Sunday (June 21, 2020) I ran the software updater and then attempted to connect to the same remote Windows machine I had connect to three days earlier. Two things happened following the update, first I received a pop-up saying "the fingerprint for the remote server has changed, do you want to continue" to which I (perhaps mistakenly) said yes. Second it popped up another message stating "Unable to connect to remote RDP server ..."

Any attempt to connect to RDP on this windows system with Remmina is met with the same message.

This seemed strange as I was regularly connecting to the same machine using my laptop - also Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without any fingerprint changes being noted. I have not performed the latest update on my laptop and it continues to have no problems connecting to the remote Windows machine.

What I have tried:

1. Based on other web info I removed the .config/freerdp/known_hosts file
2. I loaded xfreerdp so I could try running RDP from the command line. This worked fine and had no problem connecting to the remote Windows host.
3. I verified that I can ping the remote system so that DNS and name resolution work properly
4. I changed the the server to the IP of the system and changed security from "negotiate" to "RDP"
5. I tried using the Remmina "Debug Window" and it shows nothing, no output, no setup, nothing. It is not clear that this is even connected to the data stream from the application.

None of these changes have made any difference in the Remmina behavior. Everything appears to be specific to the Windows host machine after the latest Ubuntu upgrade, as my connections to other (Linux) machines using RDP with Remmina work without issues.

At present my workaround it to not update my laptop so that I can still access the remote machine using Remmina. The only other alternative is xfreerdp which works, but it much slower and does not have the same feature set.